# PyQt4 button click registering multiple times when clicked

Tags: python, user-interface, pyqt4

I am new to PyQt4 and after several searches I have not found info on the issue I am seeing in my GUI.

The issue is that when a user clicks on getSingleItems button, the function runs the same amount of times that the user has clicked getAllItems. An example is if the user clicks getAllItems to populate the items field, and then they click on getSingleItem, getitems runs once and they will get the result printed once per expectation. But if the user selects another item from list and clicks on getAllItems again, then on getSingleItem, the results is that getitem runs 2x and therefore prints 2x. This increments with each run through so clicking getAllItems 4x, even without changing selection, then clicking getitem will run 4x with a single click on getSingleItem. Only way to refresh it is to close the GUI and reopen. Any help is appreciated.

```
class UpdateItem(QDialog, updateitem_ui.Ui_updateitem):
    def __init__(self):
        QDialog.__init__(self)
        self.setupUi(self)

        tests = ['Test1', 'Test2', 'Test3']

        self.list.addItems(tests)
        self.exit.clicked.connect(self.close)

        self.setFocus()

        self.getAllItems.clicked.connect(self.getitems)

    def getitems(self):
        self.items.clear()

        self.items.addItems(self.list.currentText())

        self.getSingleItem.clicked.connect(self.getitem)

    def getitem(self):
        self.item_id = self.items.currentText()
        print(self.item_id)

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
gui = UpdateItem()
gui.show()
app.exec_()
```

Comment: Your `getitems()` method does a connect on click. Shouldn't that be in the `__init__`?

Comment: You are correct. That simple change fixed it. I will have to move the rest of my connects to __init___. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apparently you are are adding new connection to `getSingleItem.clicked` in each run of  `getitems`,
so the `clicked` signal gets connected multiple times to the same slot,
which causes the behaviour you observe.

Moving the line

```
self.getSingleItem.clicked.connect(self.getitem)
```

from `getitems` to `__init__` should fix the issue, I guess.

Comment: Thank you! That worked beautifully. Simple change that I could not for the life of me find. Thanks again!